# Create a new customer in the sandbox receive a 500 error. Google Reseller API v1

Tags: sandbox, google-reseller-api

I have authenticated my request and when I'm trying to create a new customer in the sandbox, i receive a 500 error.

Request:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/apps/reseller/v1sandbox/customers
{
 "customerDomain": "test.com",
 "kind": "reseller#customer"
}
```

Response:

```
500 Internal Server Error
- Show headers -
{
 "error": {
  "code": 500,
  "message": null
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

search the word "required" in this page
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reseller/v1/reference/customers#resource

Comment: I filled all fields and i get always this 500 error